# could not build wheels for maturin which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: installation, jupyter, maturin

/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files $ pip install maturin
Collecting maturin
Using cached maturin-1.2.3.tar.gz (175 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: tomli>=1.1.0 in /data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from maturin) (2.0.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: maturin
Building wheel for maturin (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for maturin (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [35 lines of output]
/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/cache/pip-build-env-u0qptc17/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/config/_apply_pyprojecttoml.py:80: SetuptoolsWarning: `install_requires` overwritten in `pyproject.toml` (dependencies)
corresp(dist, value, root_dir)
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-39
creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/maturin
copying maturin/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/maturin
copying maturin/**main**.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/maturin
copying maturin/import_hook.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-39/maturin
running egg_info
creating maturin.egg-info
writing maturin.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to maturin.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to maturin.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to maturin.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'maturin.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'maturin.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*.json' under directory 'src/python_interpreter'
writing manifest file 'maturin.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
running build_rust
error: can't find Rust compiler

```
  If you are using an outdated pip version, it is possible a prebuilt wheel is available for this package but pip is not able to install from it. Installing from the wheel would avoid the need for a Rust compiler.

  To update pip, run:

      pip install --upgrade pip

  and then retry package installation.

  If you did intend to build this package from source, try installing a Rust compiler from your system package manager and ensure it is on the PATH during installation. Alternatively, rustup (available at https://rustup.rs) is the recommended way to download and update the Rust compiler toolchain.
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for maturin
Failed to build maturin
ERROR: Could not build wheels for maturin, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I have tried to install jupyter notebook and I got an error regarding missing maturin . When I tried to install it I got the above error.

Comment: related? https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/17405